# If my question includes the tag of the book I'm asking about, should I still include the book's title in my question's title?

Tags: discussion

Basically, just what the title says: **If my question includes the tag of the book I'm asking about, should I still include the book's title in my question's title?**

Answer (score 5):

### Not necessarily.

This is covered on main meta at [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

> **it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles.**
>
> The only time you should use tags in your title is when *they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.*

Tags are already provided in ... well, in the tags. You don't need them in the title too.

Note that it can still be *OK* to have tags in the title, just not *necessary*. As suggested by the second part of the above quote, a title like "Why did XYZ happen in *The Lord of the Rings*?" could be perfectly fine - just not something like "[Lord of the Rings] Why did XYZ happen?"

Comment: This is what I thought, but several people have edited my questions to include the title anyway.

Comment: That is referring to titles like "[Fantastic Beasts] Why does XYZ happen?", I believe, not just naturally including the name in the question (which is **very helpful** in my opinion).

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes, hence the second part of the quote. "[Fantastic Beasts] Why does XYZ happen?" is a bad title, but "Why does XYZ happen in Fantastic Beasts?" is fine (although there's still no need to *edit* tags *into* titles).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh, I thought the question was asking whether it should be "Why does XYZ happen?" vs "Why does XYZ happen in Fantastic Beasts?" (in which case, I prefer the latter).

Answer (score 2):

**Tags and title are two different things.** You should aim to write a clear title, and aim to have clear tags. You *shouldn't* consider them to supplement each other; they each stand on their own, and serve different purposes.

Things that do work as a title:

> Why was Keats' "Hyperion" unfinished?

Things that don't work as a title:

> [Hyperion] [John Keats] Why was this unfinished?
>
> Why was this poem unfinished? (tagged: [hyperion] [john-keats])

In other words, don't shoehorn information into your title, but don't leave unsaid things that *should* be in the title even if they're also in the tags.